# Add Dataset to Another Dataset Like a DataRow in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

```
            sqlHelper = new SqlHelper();
            sqlHelper.OpenConnection();
            int i;
            String sqlSt = string.Empty;
            for (i = 0; i < tag.Count; i++)
            {
               sqlSt = "Select TagID from TagsList where TagName= '" + tag[i] + "'";
               ds = sqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(sqlSt, CommandType.Text);

               if (ds != null)
               {
                   if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                   {
                       //dt = ds1.Tables[0];
                       ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds);
                   }
               }
             }
             return ds;
```

I want to add one DataSet to another and in the end the cumulative DataSet would be returned.

I am getting an error - `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Data.DataSet>`

**EDIT:** Want i want is that i get a Dataset that consists of a particular int value each type my for loop runs i want to Add the all these records into the DataSet and then return my Dataset

Comment: You must row by row to the DataTable. Instead of Add() use ImportRow()

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is a typo since you are adding the same DataSet to its first table's rows collection:

> ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds);

If I understand correctly you have a DataSet `ds1` and you would like to add its tables to `ds`. For this you will need to move table by table in two steps: **cloning the table and importing its rows**.

For example, this copies the first table (index 0):

```
//clone first table
DataTable dt = ds1.Tables[0].Clone();
//add rows
foreach (DataRow dr in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    dt.ImportRow(dr);
}
//add table to DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

**Edited**:
I would also look into the `DataTableExtensions` [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx). It believe you can also just do (untested):

```
//copy first table
DataTable dt = ds1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();    
//add table to DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you are going to check a value and depending on this value you will add the records? and finally return the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Technically We cant add One Dataset To Other Dataset,Because DataSets in ASP.NET are usually read-only.

So,First We Have To Create Object Reference of Second DataSet.

Steps :

```
bool IsFirstTime  = true;(Create OutSide Loop)
```

Inside Loop :

```
if (IsFirstTime)

{

// dsLoopData Contains Records

dsTotalRecords = dsLoopData.Clone();

IsFirstTime = false;

}
```

1.At a Time Insert (For Bulk Copy)

```
dsTotalRecords.Tables[0].Merge(dsLoopData.Tables[0]);
```

2.Row By Row Insertion

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsLoopData.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)

{

dsTotalRecords.Tables[0].ImportRow(dsLoopData.Tables[0].Rows[i]);

}
```